# Can node.js and JS Frameworks make use of ES6 out of the box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I read that ES6 was released as and a lot of web browsers support it, I want to now if I can use ES6 features and syntax out of the box in the newest version of node.js and js frameworks like angular.js or react.js ?

Comment: Yes and no: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only relevant/valid for some time.

Comment: @FelixKling—there's an awful lot of red in that table, and much of it in the "newest" versions (though updates seem to be frequent), so I'd say the pendulum is heavily in the "no" camp. For now. ;-)

Comment: @FelixKing, many questions and answers on SO will be irrelevant in 20 years ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Node/IO.js can use ES6 out of the box, but support is still limited today. As Felix King noted, you can check the partial support at:

> http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6

To enable ES6 features in Node.js you can run node with the `harmony` argument, but be aware that it enables both stable and unstable features:

```
node --harmony app.js
```

If you use IO.js most stable ES6 features are included by default, however they also have the `harmony` argument that enables additional *staging* and *in progress* features of ES6, so bottom line is that IO.js gives you stable ES6 support out of the box, but you can get additional stuff using the `harmony` argument.

```
iojs --harmony app.js
```

> https://iojs.org/en/es6.html

Since the ES6 support in Node/IO.js is still partial, to get full ES6 support in Node you should use a **Transpiler**.

For Angular and React, to get ES6 support for the main stuff (classes, arrow funcs etc.) across all browsers you must use a Transpiler, and you have many many options. Some of the most popular are **TypeScript**, **Babel**, and **Traceur**.

There are many differences between these, and it depends on what you want. If you want pure ES6/ES7 support, i would go with **Babel**. If you want optional types and additional features (e.g. Generics) you should go with **TypeScript**.

However, Babel has the best tooling today, and i would stick to it for both front-end (Angular/React) and backend (Node).

> https://babeljs.io/

If you are interested to read more about the need for Transpilers read:

http://www.ministryofprogramming.com/typescript-is-the-new-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Right now you need to use something to compile your ES6 to ES5. For example this: https://babeljs.io/.

Here is a seed (without docs yet) that uses babeljs.

https://github.com/ottogiron/node-hapi-seed

With that you can write ES6 and feel like you are using it "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Before we started getting all gitty about Harmony and Babel, CoffeeScript has been spearheading the future for years already. So as a rule of thumb, just ask yourself: can I use CoffeeScript here? The answer, as I said, is most likely yes!

Caveat emptor: depending on the context where your using ES6, you might want to ask yourself what qualifies as being *useful* at the moment.

For instance, React.js has great support for ES6 classes, but unfortunately there is no support for mixins and you'll have to resort to writing higher-order components instead; Node.js has support for generators, but the implementation may not be as mature in terms of performances, etc.

Comment: I want to use  Promises to manage Async. I use bluebird to do that, but I was thinking in get rid of it because I thought EC6 was officialy released